# Working with two different languages in R (Windows 10)

Tags: r, encoding, locale, cyrillic

I have a problem using R with two different sets of characters. Specifically when I use Serbian Latin and Macedonian Cyrillic.

When my system locale is set to Serbian Latin I can use and manipulate unique Serbian characters (čćšđ), however then Macedonian Cyrillic appear as  in the R console and when I save them as csv.

When I change my system locale to Cyrillic then it's the other way around. I can read and write Cyrillic but not the Serbian Latin characters.

Is there a way for me to use both in the same R session?

Comment: It looks like your system uses Language-specific encoding. Have you tried to use UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: How do I do that exactly? When my Windows is set to default (USA English) I can't use either of those sets of characters. That is why I changed the locale, to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too generic to be answered; provide more info and I will be glade to edit it to a proper answer for future readers.

Assuming you are using RStudio the default encoding is the system encoding. This is why you are getting the described behaviour. You should set your RStudio default encoding to UTF-8, overriding the system locale. Further pay attention to wich character format are you saving your csv to.

Comment: On the contrary, it isn't generic at all. R and R Studio *do* have severe issues with Unicode. R was written using ASCII strings (char) instead of Unicode (char16_t) and depends on the OS to use a UTF8 language encoding in order to process Unicode data. Windows though is a Unicode OS and *encodings* refer to non-Unicode applications. Ie there is no UTF8 encoding. There is no need when all applications are built for Unicode.

Comment: 2)  R's code was modified to use Unicode (char16_t) only on Windows and keeps using char on Linux. Most functions that are affected by codepage issues allow you to specify the codepage. After all, a Serbian may want to read a Turkish data file. Unfortunately, many packages *and* R Studio still depend on the system encoding. And forget about handling multiple codepages - they don't allow you to specify the encoding

Comment: 3) Finally, R Studio itself has issues. You have to *explicitly* specify that scripts are saved and loaded as UTF8, otherwise they are saved using the current locale's codepage. This isn't apparent until you try to read a script and find that the text values are garbled or replaced with boxes or `?` characters

Comment: Thanks for your comments. My current "solution" is to use linux virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

The following link provides a lot of details about encoding. I think it could be helpful to have a look a it. Good luck.

Visit https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/279354_f552c4c41852439f910ad620763960b6.html